# JAVA: Scanner doesn't accept space for char datatype?

Tags: java, input, char, java.util.scanner, datainputstream

THIS QUESTION IS SPECIFIC TO char DATATYPE. NOT STRING.
Scanner class in Java doesn't accept blank space as an input for *char* datatype.

```
Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
char a = obj.next().charAt(0);
```

For this specific reason, I'm forced to use DataInputStream or BufferedReader!

```
DataInputStream obj = new DataInputStream(System.in);
char a = obj.readChar();
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: This question is about char datatype not String

Comment: A) did you try the suggested workaround in duplicate of setting the delimiter to "'" [I have no idea if it would help; I try to avoid using java.util.scanner if at all possible]
B) You're doing obj.next() which returns a string; by the time you do .charAt, it's too late
C) <rant>If Java weren't written by weenies, you could probably use nextByte()</rant>

Comment: `Scanner` simply doesn't have a `char` type version of `next()`, whether whitespace or not. But `Scanner` is intended to capture *tokens* from your text, separated by delimiters. Could you explain further in what sense this blank space is a *token* in your input?

Comment: I was trying to use Character wrapper class' isWhiteSpace function, that's where I discovered that Scanner won't accept blank spaces